# Create a switched connection for a car AV receiver being used as a home audio system

Tags: audio

I was recently gifted a Sony XAV-AX5550D car AV receiver but, alas, I have no car! (I was thinking of getting one, but things as they are...) I thought of selling it but have had VERY low offers. So I decided to profit from its rather good sound quality and turn it into my main home audio system.

It's up and running perfectly with both the red and yellow leads connected to an AC-to-DC (12V 10A) converter. On the one hand, it just feels wrong to have to cut the power to the converter to turn off the device--though I understand that's what would basically happen in a car. But I would like to know if there's a way I can create a switch using the red lead. Especially because every time I turn it off, certain things like the time and date are reset because, as I see in the manual, the memory circuit needs constant power to the yellow lead in order to function.

Any ideas?

P.S. I'm not sure if this is the best SE community for this question but all others somehow seem less adequate. If you think it's "off-topic", please let me know where might be a better place to ask this. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a switch in the red lead.

Even an inline table lamp switch would suffice, the voltage is low and so is the current.

Or you could get a small on/off round button type switch and mount it neatly in a bracket.

Comment: Hi, @Solar Mike! Thanks for your answer! I can't believe it's that simple...  I thought of trying that but then said to myself: obviously that won't work. Hahaha. I'm going to try that right away.

Comment: Why not just turn off the converter ? An inline switch is just doing the same. Unless you’re powering both switch and permanent live to keep the sound and memory presets you gain absolutely no benefit to an inline switch

Comment: @DanK because the OP mentions that - wants to have the stored presets continue through successive uses...

Comment: As @SolarMike mentions, the whole issue revolves around maintaining the presets and configuration. In fact, as I've set it up right now, it's more practical for me in terms of turning on and off because I have the converter plugged into a remote-controlled outlet. BUT the possibility of losing my EQ setup if I don't turn it on in a couple of days, for instance, in the end makes it less practical than having to deal with a switch.